# Text-align justify not working?

Tags: css

I'm working on a website and I have this CSS:

```
#aboutMe
{
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
    -webkit-border-radius: 400px;
    -moz-border-radius: 400px;
    border-radius: 400px;
    background:#48c7ff;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    font-family:'Ciclef';
    color:#e9e9e9;
    padding:35px;
    line-height:25px;
}

#aboutMe p
{
    text-align:justify;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

However, the text isn't justified, it's left aligned.  How can I fix this?

Here's the website: http://ibdesigns.net23.net/

The "About Me" circle (about halfway down the page) is the paragraph giving me trouble.

Comment: The way I see it, text in the circle is justified. There's a problem with the text "My work" getting covered by the four circles at the bottom of the page. By the way, how did you make the wave between the green and blue halves of the page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That text is [justified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_%28typesetting%29). The last line in a justified paragraph does not get stretched (or compressed) to fit on that line.

To make it look better (in CSS3 browsers that support [`text-align-last`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last)), you could do:

```
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:center;
/* for IE9 */
-ms-text-align-last:center;
```

Comment: @kai-o-pele: That also works, but aesthetically, it depends on how much text is rendered on that last line (it could be three words, very far apart).

Answer (score 0):

And by the way, did you observe the same `<div>`? The text is moving out of the image; you may consider a small CSS change:

```css
#aboutMe p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I added **`margin-left: 15px;`**.